# sqlalchemt---SAWarning: fully NULL primary key identity cannot load any object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

**model:**

```
'''任务工单'''
    __tablename__ = 'task'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True, nullable=False)
    dep_id = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True, nullable=False)
    title = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False, index=True)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    cate = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, default=1,`enter code here`)
    add_time = db.Column(db.Integer, default=int(time.time()), comment="添加时间")
    is_top = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, default=0, comment="是否加急 1--加急 0--不加急")
    desgin_id = db.Column(db.Integer,comment="设计人员的id")
    update_time = db.Column(db.Integer, comment="修改时间")
    review_time = db.Column(db.Integer, comment="审核时间")
    assignment_time = db.Column(db.Integer, comment='分配时间')
    fiannce_time = db.Column(db.Integer, comment='完成时间')
    invalid_time = db.Column(db.Integer, comment='无效时间')
    desgin_time = db.Column(db.Integer, comment="开始设计时间")
    state = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, default=1, comment="状态：1--初始化待分配 2--带设计 3--设计中 4--提交待审核(审核中) 5--驳回  7--完成 0--无效")
```

**use:**

```
 taskDicts = Task.query.filter_by(state=state).order_by(desc(Task.is_top),asc(Task.add_time)).offset(offset).limit(10).all()
```

> venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py:246:
>   SAWarning: fully NULL primary key identity cannot load any object.

This condition may raise an error in a future release.

Comment: This warning is emitted when a null primary key is passed to `session.get`, for example `session.get(SomeModel, None)`.  The code in this question does not issue the warning.